# AWS Serverless framework: Missing lower version constraint

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am building an AWS serverless framework yaml file,  I am trying to deploy it to an enclosed server that requires I set the upper and lower version constraint. This is how I have set it up

```
service: helloer-service
frameworkVersion: '>=1.5 <2.0'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: eu-central-1

functions:
  helloer:
    handler: helloer.hello_handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /hello
          method: get
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(1 minute)
```

but everytime I try to run it I end up getting an error

> deployment_structure_test.go:52:  Error
> Trace:    deployment_structure_test.go:52 Error:          Should be true
> Test:         TestVerifyDeploymentFrameworkVersionIsCorrect Messages:
> Missing lower version constraint.

what am I doing wrong, your help is appreciated